# Get the most popular product per day, MySQL for Magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I need to get a table that contains the most popular product sold per day. All data is stored in Magento, and I use MySQL to write the query. The only table I need is `Sales_flat_order_item` table.

The final table should have 3 columns: `Date`, `Product SKU`, and number of units sold of the most popular product that day - `MaxQty`.

I came up with the query that works for me, but I would like to know how it can be improved since I use the same subquery twice in my code:

1 Select `Date`, `Product Id`, `Sku`, and `Quantity` from `sales_flat_order_item` - Subquery1

2 Select `Date` and `Maximum Quantity` from `Subquery1` - Subquery2

3 Join them together knowing that dates should be the same, and Quantity from Subquery1 should be equal to Maximum Quantity from Subquery2

```
SELECT DATE( sq2.created_at ) AS CreatedAt, sq0.sku AS SKU, sq2.MaxQty
FROM (

SELECT created_at, product_id, sku, SUM( qty_ordered ) AS qty
FROM  `sales_flat_order_item` 
GROUP BY DATE( created_at ) , product_id
) AS sq0
JOIN (

SELECT sq.created_at, MAX( sq.qty ) AS MaxQty
FROM (

SELECT created_at, product_id, SUM( qty_ordered ) AS qty
FROM  `sales_flat_order_item` 
GROUP BY DATE( created_at ) , product_id
) AS sq
GROUP BY DATE( sq.created_at )
) AS sq2 ON DATE( sq2.created_at ) = DATE( sq0.created_at ) 
AND sq2.MaxQty = sq0.qty
GROUP BY DATE( CreatedAt )
```

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: What if 2 products are equally popular

Comment: @Strawberry - it's a good question. At this moment, I just pick any of them randomly until I come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want.
I added a `WHERE` clause to run it only for this month, in case you have a huge database so it should not take much time.

```
SELECT day, sku, MAX(qty_total) AS qty FROM (
    SELECT DATE(created_at) AS day, sku, SUM(qty_ordered) AS qty_total
    FROM `sales_flat_order_item` 
    WHERE created_at > '2015-07%'
    GROUP BY sku, day
    ORDER BY qty_total DESC
) AS item_count
GROUP BY day
```